# Correct Fuse Sizing

Tags: power-supply, transformer, fuses

How can I correctly select the size of the fuse on the primary side of a transformer based on a transformer? The regulators in this circuit are an LM317 and an LM337 which draw a maximum of 1.5 amps, so that would be 3 amps Max on the secondary side. What fuse does this translate to on the primary? What is the general formula for solving this problem/ rules of thumb to follow, etc? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is the rating of the transformer?

Comment: There are several other issues in your circuit. 22uF capacitor won't allow 1.5A of output current, and the LM317 is not a negative voltage regulator. What is the transformer output voltage and what are the output voltages and currents you need?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake. It should be a 22mF capacitor, not uF.

Comment: @ Andrew Morton: As an example, 24-0-24 volts, and 50 watts.

Comment: @DavidGraham And what is the input voltage for the transformer? Work out the input current at the maximum VA or W rating of the transformer and pick a slow-blow fuse of about twice that current, probably 0.5 A if it's on 240 V. [This article](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/fuses/solution-center/bus-ele-tech-lib-transformer-protection.pdf) suggests 3x for a small transformer like that. I am not a qualified electrical engineer.

Comment: I'm in the mainland of China now, the input voltage is 220 Volts at 50 Hertz. Thank you! :) I'm reading the link you sent me.

Comment: You are right @Andrew Morton, and now I can see why you picked the 1/2 amp fuse. P=IV so 50W = I*220 Volts works out to 220 mA. I can see why you chose .5 amps. Thanks for the reminder about that. I'm fusing not for what the circuit will actually draw, but what the transformer is capable of handling at max draw, to protect the transformer. –